# How does a Google iOS app save and restore active accounts across app deletion?

Tags: security, ios, google, privacy, google-hangouts

On an iOS 8 device, I installed Google Hangouts and upon first launch, it pre-populated an account that was previously associated with a different, and long ago deleted, Google app.

Since I had just Reset Advertising Identifier, I assumed it must be the Vendor ID (there was another Google app installed on the device). So, I deleted both (all) Google apps on the device, which *should* reset the Vendor ID.

I then re-installed Google Hangouts and launched it. It STILL had the old account active. This is not only mysterious behavior, but is also a pretty serious security and privacy vulnerability. When an app is deleted, and especially when all apps from a vendor are deleted, there should be no active accounts or data left on the device.

Any ideas on how Google Hangouts knows about the old account?

Answer (score 1):

Apple advises developers to store app login credentials in the encrypted iOS Keychain. When you delete an app from your phone it doesn't delete the related records from the Keychain.

> Keychains are secure storage containers, which means
>   that when the keychain is locked, no one can access its protected
>   contents. In OS X, users can unlock a keychain—thus providing trusted
>   applications access to the contents—by entering a single master
>   password. In iOS, each application always has access to its own
>   keychain items; the user is never asked to unlock the keychain.
>   Whereas in OS X any application can access any keychain item provided
>   the user gives permission, in iOS an application can access only its
>   own keychain items.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html

Comment: This seems to be the most likely mechanism, but If this is indeed the mechanism Google is using (or any app for that matter), it seems insanely insecure and a severe privacy violation. I got access to another person's Google login simply by installing an app from Google when no other Google apps existed on the device. It looks like there is a way that newly installed apps should clean up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747404/delete-keychain-items-when-an-app-is-uninstalled but Hangouts didn't do this. There also does not seem to be a way for a user to delete non-Safari Keychain items.

Comment: It's a big Apple security/privacy problem that Keychain items are not cleared when an app is deleted (or, worst case when the last of a vendor's apps is deleted). It's also an Apple problem that there is no easy way for users to delete individual (non-Safari) Keychain items. And it's a Google security/privacy problem that they allow a login to persist across app deletion (including deleting all Google apps).

Comment: I don't agree that this is a big security/privacy problem. If someone gave you their device and was concerned about their data they should have wiped it first. I'd never give a device to someone with data still on it. There is no mechanism for an app to delete its keychain items, so you can't really fault Google here either. I would agree though that it would be good if Apple gave us a way for us to edit our keychain, similar to the way you can go into Safari settings on an iOS device and edit the saved credentials.

Comment: Yes, if I was getting rid of a device, I'd wipe it, though I'm sure many people forget to or don't know how. But I do think this is very counterintuitive behavior. It's common to share an iPad among family and/or friends, but that shouldn't imply persistent active logins to deleted apps.

Comment: Another use case is deleting the app (or even all apps in the app group), but later wanting to re-install an app with with a new identity not linked to the old one. If the old data restores from backup, this becomes impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It probably uses iCloud as a method, possibly the [iCloud Key-Value Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html).

As far as that storage goes…

> The total space available in your app’s iCloud key-value storage is 1
>   MB per user. The maximum number of keys you can specify is 1024, and
>   the size limit for each value associated with a key is 1 MB. For
>   example, if you store a single large value of exactly 1 MB for a
>   single key, that fully consumes your quota for a given user of your
>   app. If you store 1 KB of data for each key, you can use 1000
>   key-value pairs. The maximum length for a key string is 64 bytes using
>   UTF8 encoding. The data size of your cumulative key strings does not
>   count against your 1 MB total quota for iCloud key-value storage;
>   rather, your key strings (which at maximum consume 64 KB) count
>   against a user’s total iCloud allotment.

(Source: Apple Developer Conceptual Reading for iCloud Key-Value Storage's Data Limits, see link above)

In short, developers can access data through iCloud's KV pairs through `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, store objects storable in an `NSDictionary` (up to 64K per item, up to 1024 keys, and the total size must be less than 1 MB), and retrieve them later.

---

Edit: iCloud Key-Value storage isn't as secure as Keychains. Google might use Keychains, but they might also store encrypted data on the Key-Value store, considering iCloud has security issues. Maybe use the device's name as a way to de-encrypt?

Comment: The Google apps had no permissions for iCloud, so more likely to be Keychain.

Comment: @pseudon KVS doesn't need permission.

Comment: Possible then. This would also be counterintuitive behavior to a user, who would never expect an app to be able to store an active login persistently in his iCloud, especially for a deleted app. Can an app use iCloud KV Store if iCloud isn't signed in or in use at all on the device?

Comment: @pseudon not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

> ...in iOS an application can access only **its own** keychain items

Vendors can share data across *their* applications, using the Keychain as long as they are using a [keychain group](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15), defined in the entitlements in their app bundle; "it's own" means vendor, not application.

As others have pointed out, the keychain entries may not get cleaned up implicitly.

Since this widest scope of this type of 'tracking' is limited to a single vendor with apps installed, this significantly reduces the security risk surface area (compared to UUID or UIPasteboard sharing - both removed/closed).

It is important to note that Apple's products are currently designed for "single users"; Apple does not yet offer user partitioning (for example, any registered fingerprint unlocks the entire device, so if you have a friend/child with a registered fingerprint, they get exactly the same access as you).

*Adding to the answers by DDPWNAGE and Alistair (since I don't have enough rep to comment) but specifying how all Google apps can access exactly one keychain entry.*